# AuthorizeNet PHP sdk ARB not updating on sandbox

Tags: php, authorize.net

The XML for the ARB update is this:

```
<subscriptionId>2313340</subscriptionId>
<subscription>
    <name>Testing Name Yearly Level 3 Subscription</name>
    <paymentSchedule>
        <interval>
            <length>12</length>
            <unit>months</unit>
        </interval>
        <startDate>2015-01-02</startDate>
        <totalOccurrences>9999</totalOccurrences>
    </paymentSchedule>
    <amount>85.2500</amount>
    <payment>
        <creditCard>
            <cardNumber>5424000000000015</cardNumber>
            <expirationDate>2015-02</expirationDate>
            <cardCode>123</cardCode>
        </creditCard>

    </payment>

    <billTo>
        <firstName>Tester First Name</firstName>
        <lastName>Tester Last Name</lastName>
        <company>Testing name</company>
        <address>Testing address</address>
        <city>Testing City</city>
        <state>Testing State</state>
        <zip>12345</zip>
    </billTo>

</subscription>
```

The id does exists on my sandbox account, problem is, it is not updating anything when I check my account, yet the response is ok.

Code for the ARB update is: `$request->updateSubscription($subscribeModel->subscription_id, $subscription)` which works okay because it produces the XML result above when I log it.

I am using the php-sdk found from here: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php

Anyone can explain why I can't update the subscription?

**UPDATE**

ARB response:

```
object(AuthorizeNetARB_Response)#326 (3) {
  ["xml"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#324 (1) {
    ["messages"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#316 (2) {
      ["resultCode"]=>
      string(5) "Error"
      ["message"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#328 (2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(6) "E00034"
        ["text"]=>
        string(43) "The interval information cannot be changed."
      }
    }
  }
  ["response"]=>
  string(396) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ARBUpdateSubscriptionResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"><messages><resultCode>Error</resultCode><message><code>E00034</code><text>The interval information cannot be changed.</text></message></messages></ARBUpdateSubscriptionResponse>"
  ["xpath_xml"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#325 (1) {
    ["messages"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#316 (2) {
      ["resultCode"]=>
      string(5) "Error"
      ["message"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#328 (2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(6) "E00034"
        ["text"]=>
        string(43) "The interval information cannot be changed."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Seems like interval can't be changed? That's weird :(

Comment: show the arb xml request and response

Comment: remove the interval and check it. Once the subscription is created,interval information cannot be changed.

Comment: @user3040610: well, that cannot apply in my application, I need to update interval sometimes. So what I do now for temporary solution is cancel the subscription and re-create it again (ugly i know)

Comment: Yes you have to cancel the subscription and create a new subscription.